# How to plot page views over time with qplot?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

I have loaded a log onto a dataframe `v`. You can see the output of `head(v)`:

```
  user_id    page_id           timestamp
1     139    1612783 2011-02-22 06:24:40
2     139    1612783 2011-02-22 06:28:40
3     139    1612783 2011-02-22 06:41:01
```

How can I `qplot` the number of `page_id`'s per day?

- On the x-axis it would be the day (e.g. `2011-02-22`).
- On the y-axis it would be the number of `page_id`'s for that particular date.

Comment: `dput()` the contents of `v` for specific help, otherwise - check out http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_datetime.html

Comment: please take the time to provide a dataset to work with in the future, as per Chase's suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
v <- data.frame(
          timestamp = as.Date(c("2011-02-22", "2011-02-22", "2011-02-23")), 
          page_id = c(1,2,1))
newdata <- data.frame(time=names(new), count=new)
qplot(time, page, data = newdata)
```

It is worth reading the ggplot [manual](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/book/qplot.pdf), which has plenty of `qplot` examples, including times series.

Answer (score 1):

```
t1 = with(v, table(as.Date(timestamp), page_id))
t2 = apply(t1 > 0, 1, sum)
dates = as.Date(names(t2))
plot(t2 ~ dates)                             # using plot
qplot(dates, t2, data=data.frame(t2, dates)) # using qplot
```

You can write this in a more compact form, but this way you can check the values of `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a graph produced with `ggplot2::qplot`, specifically.

Comment: I disagree but appreciate the help on the calculation. That is why I originally just added qplot to your answer and deleted my own.